# NoMethodError: private method `open' called for #<URI::Generic:0x000055d4f2e16f00>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

NoMethodError: private method `open' called for # (Most recent call first)
File /app/app/interactors/order/store_purchases.rb line 55 in store_purchase

## store_purchase:

```
...

purchase.capture.attach(io: URI.parse(context.capture).open, filename: context.capture)
...
```

This error on only on heroku deploy... What I did wrong? Help me please

Answer (score 6):

It seems that you did not include `open-uri`.

https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.3/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI.html

Try this

```rb
require 'open-uri'

URI.parse(context.capture).open
```

Answer (score 2):

`URI#open` *is* private on older Ruby versions, for example 2.2. You need to use a different method (such as the global `open` provided by `open-uri`, though this is questionable from the security standpoint) on those Rubies. Or use a newer Ruby version.

Comment: It calls the open as a public method if the argument contains (http:// or https://)

Comment: It will call `URI#open` as long as you require `open-uri`. The security risk is mitigated by calling it on the parsed URI - `URI.parse(url_string).open`

Comment: I don't think this is an _"older Ruby versions"_ thing. I just installed ruby 3.1.2 and in a fresh irb session the `open` method is _still_ private until I `require open-uri`.